# How to securely use Google Drive SDK for external users to upload to my Drive via my php code

Tags: google-apps, google-drive-api

I've read that Service Accounts might be a good idea for allowing customers to upload their files for use on our website. However I've also read that Drive SDK isn't setup with service accounts for security reasons.

We're looking for users to be able to upload brochures to us which are used on our site. This is mainly for the Google Docs document render functionality rather than storage space.

E.g

User uploads file through our site
File is uploaded to Google Docs
Uploaded URL / file id is passed back to us for us to store / reference in DB.
On our site Brochures appear as pop ups of the Google page displaying the doc.

We will want to do more things in the future that use the Drive SDK functionality so don't want to rule out using it.

Any suggestions?

Kind regards,

Joe

Answer (score 0):

The Drive SDK supports service accounts and the documentation includes samples in multiple languages explaining how to use them:

https://developers.google.com/drive/service-accounts